# A design pattern for chaining together Trys that may not all be neccessary

Tags: scala

I have a lot of code that has to call functions that return `Try`. The only reason that they return `Try` is to show errors. The success value isn't actually important.

Sometimes not all these functions need to be called, depending on some conditionals. For example, suppose I am given an update form and I only want to update the database for things that were changed.

I can do this with

```
for {
    _ <- if(precidate1) funtionReturningTry else Success(-1)
    // ...
    _ <- if(precidateN) anotherFuntionReturningTry else Success(-1)
} yield someUnrelatedId
```

One problem with this is that it can create quite a bit of clutter since we must create some discarded `Success` value to show that we are skipping that step of the comprehension. For more complicated types, this is a bit messier since we must return some dummy type. Above all, those `else` statements are nothing but noise.

It'd be ideal if we could use something *like* guards. We can't use guards here because if a guard fails, the entire comprehension fails.

Obviously a for comprehension works great when all our function calls are necessary, but it doesn't seem to make it easy to skip function calls. Does anyone know a clean design pattern for chaining together such statements when some may be optional?

Comment: could you use collectFirst on your function list or Try's orElse perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just wrap this in another function? If you don't care about the return types of `Try[A]` (other than failures), then you can discard them to `Unit`, for example.

```
def tryIf[A](condition: Boolean)(f: => Try[A]): Try[Unit] = {
    if(condition) f.map(_ => ()) else Success(())
}
```

Then your for-comprehension would look like this:

```
for {
    _ <- tryIf(precidate1)(funtionReturningTry)
   ...
    _ <- tryIf(precidateN)(anotherFuntionReturningTry)
} yield ...
```

No more `else`s and dummy values for arbitrary types.

Comment: If you can make `A` a monoid, you could use `Success(Monoid[A].zero)` in the else case.